# how to retrieve the values of the attributes of a nested class in a view?

Tags: c#, razor

I am busy in my homecontroller.cs (in a MVC Razor project) where I send a class looking like the following one to my view:

```
    private class Evt 
    {   
        public SEvent Event { get; set; }
        public String Duration { get; set; }
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SEvent> modFromWcf = proxy.GetAllEventsByPeriod(@System.DateTime.Now.Year, @System.DateTime.Now.Year + 1, "EN").ToList();
        List<Evt> modTosend = new List<Evt>();

        foreach (SEvent item in modFromWcf)
        {
            Evt ES = new Evt();
            ES.Event = item;
            ES.Duration = GetDuration(item.StartDate ,item.EndDate);   
            modTosend.Add(ES);
        };

        return View("Index", modTosend);
    }
```

SEvent is just another class.

In my view I try to do something with some of the attributes, but I do not know how to retrieve the values of that class Event. This is my code:

```
@{ 
    foreach (var item in ViewData.Model) {
    string year = item.Event.StartDate.Year.ToString();
    }
    ....
}
```

The error that I receive is: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Event'. But I CAN debug and see that item DOES consist ofa class Event and a string Duration. I can see the contents too. Does somebody know how I can retrieve e.g. item.Event.StartData??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly define item.
`ViewData.Model` will return a collection of objects, and objects do not have Event properties.

Something like this should work:

```
@{ 
    foreach (var item in ViewData.Model) {
        if (item is Evt){
            Evt itemEvt = (Evt)item;
            string year = itemEvt.Event.StartDate.Year.ToString();
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Though I usually do something like:

```
@{ 
    foreach (Evt item in ViewData.Model) {
        string year = item.Event.StartDate.Year.ToString();
    }
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `item` to your class.

`ViewData` is of type `ViewDataDictionary`, which implements `IDictionary<string, Object>`, indicating that it is a dictionary matching keys of type `string` to values of type `object`.

Use this to make your code run as is:

```
@{ 
    foreach (var item in ViewData.Model) {
    string year = ((Evt)item).Event.StartDate.Year.ToString();
    }
    ....
}
```

However, you should probably be using a strongly typed view for this instead of shoving data into `ViewData` for this.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution. What I am wondering is: Can I make a partial view strongly typed? I'll research that. The only problem I'm still having now is: ((Evt)item).Event.StartDate.Month.ToString("MMMM") will give me "MMMM", instead of a month name.

Comment: Partial views can be strongly typed, you would usually just put them inside of a container view that itself isn't strongly typed.

Comment: Also, Your string format isn't working because you're applying the format not to the DateTime, but to its Year property, which is an int. You should just be using StartDate.ToString("MMMM").